# Angular 2 Template Driven Forms - Array Input Elements

Tags: forms, angular, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have been struggling for 1 and half day and still couldn't find any solution to the problem. I am working on simple form which has `select` and `checkboxes` element.When I try submitting the form I do not get the values of `select` and `checkboxes` but rather I just get true in the console.
I am working on template driven form.

```
<form (ngSubmit)="addSubcontractor(subcontractorForm)" #subcontractorForm="ngForm">
      <h5>Type :</h5>
         <div class="form-group">
             <div *ngFor="let contractor_type of contractor_types;let i = index;" class="pull-left margin-right">
             <label htmlFor="{{ contractor_type | lowercase }}">
                            {{ contractor_type }} :
            </label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="_contractor_type[{{i}}]" [value]="contractor_type" ngModel>
        </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control costcodelist" name="_cc_id[]"  multiple="true" ngModel>
        //When I put ngModel on select I just keep getting error
        //TypeError: values.map is not a function
           <option *ngFor="let costcode of costcodes" [selected]="costcode.id == -1" [value]="costcode.id">{{ costcode.costcode_description }}</option>
         </select>
    </div>
   </form>
```

Component Section

```
export class SubcontractorComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
   private contractor_types = ['Subcontractor', 'Supplier', 'Bank', 'Utility'];
   constructor(private costcodeService: CostcodeService, 
               private subcontractorService: SubcontractorService) { 

     this.subcontractorService.initializeServices();
   }
   ngOnInit() {

       this.costcode_subscription = this.costcodeService.getAll()
                                    .subscribe(
                                    (costcodes) => {
                                       this.costcodes = costcodes;
                                     });

  }
  addSubcontractor(form: NgForm) {
     console.log(form.value);
  }
}
```

When I remove `ngModel` from `select` element the code runs fine and When I submit the form I get the following output.

```
_contractor_type[0]:true
_contractor_type[1]:true
_contractor_type[2]:true 
_contractor_type[3]:""
```

I do not get the checkboxes values as well the selected options from select element.

Your comments and answer will appreciated a lot.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple selection that i use with my Template driven form.

```
    <form #f="ngForm" (submit)="addOperator(f.valid)" novalidate>
        <label>Name</label>

        <input [(ngModel)]="operator.name" name="name">
        <label >Service</label>
        <select #service="ngModel" name="service" [(ngModel)]="operator.service">
            <option *ngFor='let service of services' [ngValue]='service'>{{service.name}}</option>
        </select>

        <label >Enabled</label>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="enabled" [(ngModel)]="operator.enabled">
        </label>

        <button type="submit">Create Operator</button>
    </form>
```

.ts

```
 operator: Operator;

 ngOnInit() {
     this.operator = <Operator>{}; // // Initialize empty object, type assertion, with this we loose type safety 
 }

 addOperator(isValid: boolean) {
     if (isValid) {
         this.operatorsService.addOperator(this.operator).then(operator => {
             this.goBack();
         });
     } 
 }
```

Also im importing this

```
 import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

Comment: What about `multi select` element and also it is two way data binding which is rather not good in my situation

Comment: Well for multi select im using `angular-2-dropdown-multiselect` dependencie with MIT licence: https://github.com/softsimon/angular-2-dropdown-multiselect

Comment: so it's actually an issue in [Angular](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9615)

Comment: Yep, with this dependencie you can style it as you want so its not a big problem. If you want i can edit answer with implementation of `angular-2-dropdown-multiselect`